# Custom class as AnyObject in tuple

Tags: swift, tuples

I'd like to use AnyObject in a tuple in order to pass on my custom class:

```
var array: [(Float, AnyObject)] = []

let number: Float = 10.0
let instance = MyClass()
```

Both ways of adding a tuple to the array do not work:

```
array += [(number, instance)]
array.append((number, instance))
```

Is it not possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add a tuple of a different type, because it's `(Float, MyClass)` and not `(Float, AnyObject)`.

Just change this:

```
let instance = MyClass()
```

into:

```
let instance: AnyObject = MyClass()
```

and it should work.

Alternatively, you can perform an explicit downcast when creating the tuple

```
array += [(number, instance as AnyObject)]
array.append((number, instance as AnyObject))
```